# Password w/ Specific Requirements Program

Tags: java

I'm currently doing an assignment for my Java programming class.

The question in the book asks for the user to create a program that uses the JOptionPane boxes to ask the user for a password. The password has to be between 6 and 10 characters, and have at least one digit, and one letter. Once this requirement is met, ask the user to verify their password. If their second input doesn't match the first, ask the original question again. Once both inputs match, display a message saying "success!".

I've gotten mine to the point where it checks for the number of characters, but I can't for the life of me, figure out how to check for digits and letters also. I've tried nested for loops that search for digits and letters, but I can't figure out a way to make it bypass the length requirement when it doesn't have a number or letter. This is my current code.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class Password{
   public static void main(String[] args){

      String input1 = "";
      String input2 = "";
      int inputLength;

      do{
         do{

            input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your password\nIt must be 6 to 10 characters and\nhave at least one digit and one letter");

            inputLength = input1.length();

         }while(inputLength < 6 || inputLength > 10);

         input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Verify Password");

      }while(!(input1.equals(input2)));

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success!");

   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for indicating that this is homework so we can help lead you to the answer instead of just providing it. Answerers - please do just that; new users who need help with homework - follow this example

Comment: Do you have any experience with regular expressions?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Regex? If yes, try to use some basic regex tutorials to write a simple regex, Otherwise, try to iterate charArray (input1.toCharArray()) and track if there is atleast one digit and one alphabet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deal with regular expression.

- **(?=.*\d)** mean at last one digit in the word
- **(?=.*[a-zA-Z])** mean at least one letter
- **{6,10}** mean between 6 and 10 characters

So the correct regex is **((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,10})**

Now look at the `.matches(String regex) method of String :)

If you can't use regex :

- Get the CharArray (`input1.toCharArray()`) and iterate.
- For each char, check if it's a number or a character
- Keep 2 boolean (for exemple num and alpha) and set them to true when you see a number of a character

Then, look at you flag, and then test this

`num && alpha && inputLenght > 6 && inputLenght < 10`

Edit:

You can use `Character.isLetter()` and `Character.isDigit()`, i think you have enough informations now !

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I ended up adding two while loops to check for digits and letters inside of the inner do loop. I set the while loops to make the boolean expressions false if the correct thing is found (I know, it seems backwards). But it makes it so the do loop will not run again if the correct characters are found. Thank you to everyone that posted, it really helped clear things up!

Here's the completed code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class Password{
   public static void main(String[] args){

      String input1 = "";
      String input2 = "";
      int inputLength;
      boolean isDigit = true;
      boolean isLetter = true;
      char c = ' ';
      char d = ' ';
      int x = 0;

      do{
         do{

            input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your password\nIt must be 6 to 10 characters and\nhave at least one digit and one letter");

            inputLength = input1.length();

            while(x < input1.length()){
               c = input1.charAt(x);

               if(Character.isDigit(c)){
                  isDigit = false;
                  break;
               }
               x++;
            }

            x = 0;
            while(x < input1.length()){
               d = input1.charAt(x);

               if(Character.isLetter(d)){
                  isLetter = false;
                  break;
               }
               x++;
            }

         }while(inputLength < 6 || inputLength > 10 || isDigit || isLetter);

         input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Verify Password");

      }while(!(input1.equals(input2)));

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success!");

   }
}
```